# Convert repetitive pattern into JSON file with python

Tags: python, json, regex, text-processing

Hope you are doing fine,

I have a data file(containing 1000s of a structured pattern of data), like below

```
PARTNER="ABC"
  ADDRESS1="ABC Country INN"
  DEPARTMENT="ABC Department"
  CONTACT_PERSON="HR"
  TELEPHONE="+91.90.XX XX X XXX"
  FAX="+01.XX.XX XX XX XX"
  EMAIL=""

PARTNER="DEF"
  ADDRESS1="DEF Malaysia"
  DEPARTMENT=""
  CONTACT_PERSON=""
  TELEPHONE="(YYY)YYYYY"
  FAX="(001)YYYYYYYY"
  EMAIL=""

PARTNER="GEH-LOP"
  ADDRESS1="GEH LOP Street"
  DEPARTMENT="HR"
  CONTACT_PERSON="Adam"
  TELEPHONE="+91.ZZ.ZZ.ZZZZ"
  FAX="+91.ZZ.ZZ.ZZZ"
  EMAIL=""
```

I tried to convert the datafile(partner.txt) to JSON with below code:

> 1. Created empty dictionaries dict1 and dict2
> 2. Reading the data file line by line
> 3. used this if not line.isspace() to make sure the linefeed is read is written in dictionary dict1
> 4. When linebreak(empty line appears) appended the content of dict1 to dict2 using dict2.update(dict1)

- ```
  import json

  dict1 = {}
  dict2 ={}

  with open("partner.txt", "r") as fh:
      out_file = open("test1.json", "w")
      for line in fh:
          if not line.isspace():
              command, description = line.strip().split("=")
              dict1[command] = description.strip('"')

          else:
              dict2.update(dict1)
              print("space found")
      json.dump(dict2,out_file,indent=1)

  out_file.close()

  print("json file created")
  ```

> But this code creates a json(test1.json) with only the single block of PARTNER

```
{
 "PARTNER": "DEF",
 "ADDRESS1": "DEF Malaysia",
 "DEPARTMENT": "",
 "CONTACT_PERSON": "",
 "TELEPHONE": "(YYY)YYYYY",
 "FAX": "(001)YYYYYYYY",
 "EMAIL": ""
}
```

**Expected Output**
I tried looking up a lot but couldn't find a way:-

```
{
"data":[
{
 "PARTNER": "ABC",
 "ADDRESS1": "ABC Country INN",
 "DEPARTMENT": "ABC Department",
 "CONTACT_PERSON": "HR",
 "TELEPHONE": "+91.90.XX XX X XXX",
 "FAX": "+01.XX.XX XX XX XX",
 "EMAIL": ""
},
{
 "PARTNER": "DEF",
 "ADDRESS1": "DEF Malaysia",
 "DEPARTMENT": "",
 "CONTACT_PERSON": "",
 "TELEPHONE": "(YYY)YYYYY",
 "FAX": "(001)YYYYYYYY",
 "EMAIL": ""
},
{
 "PARTNER": "GEH-LOP",
 "ADDRESS1": "GEH LOP Street",
 "DEPARTMENT": "HR",
 "CONTACT_PERSON": "Adam",
 "TELEPHONE": "+91.ZZ.ZZ.ZZZZ",
 "FAX": "+91.ZZ.ZZ.ZZZ",
 "EMAIL": ""
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set dict1 to a new dict each time:

```
import json
dict1 = {}
dict2 ={}

with open("partner.txt", "r") as fh:
    out_file = open("test1.json", "w")
    for line in fh:
        if not line.isspace():
            command, description = line.strip().split("=")
            dict1[command] = description.strip('"')    
        else:
            dict2.update(dict1)
            dict1 = {}                             # set it to new dict
            print("space found")
    json.dump(dict2,out_file,indent=1)

out_file.close()

print("json file created")
```

Comment: It will still overwrite even if you instantiate the dict with every loop. dict2 gets overwritten every time because the keys are the same. The real solution is to create a list of dicts using append and then making that the value of "data"

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the dict to a list of dictionaries, not use update, as it overwrites the keys that are always the same:

```
import json
dict1 = {}
data = []

with open("partner.txt", "r") as fh:
    out_file = open("test1.json", "w")
    for line in fh:
        if not line.isspace():
            command, description = line.strip().split("=")
            dict1[command] = description.strip('"')    
        else:
            data.append(dict1)
            dict1 = {}                             # set it to new dict
            print("space found")
    output = {'data': data}
    json.dump(output, out_file, indent=1)

out_file.close()

print("json file created")
```

Comment: Thanks, @Swagga, It worked very fine. I appreciate your solution!

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this. maybe we should make it maintainable

```py
def list_to_dict(lines):
    obj = {}
    for liner in lines:
        idx = liner.find("=")
        obj[liner[0:idx]] = liner[idx + 2 : len(liner) - 1]
    return obj


with open("file", "r") as f:
    results = []
    group = []
    for line in list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.read().split("\n"))):
        if line == "":
            results.append(list_to_dict(group))
            group = []
        else:
            group.append(line)

    print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks @D. Seah, Your solution too worked! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Using **`regex` + `json` + `dict/list-comprehension`**

You can do this using the `regex` (regular expression) and `json` libraries together. The text-processing is carried out with `regex` and finally the `json` library is used to format the dictionary into JSON format and write to a `.json` file.

Additionally we use *dict and list comprehensions* to gather the intended fields.

**Note:**

> The `regex pattern` used here is as follows:
>
> ```py
> # longer manually written version
> pat = r'PARTNER="(.*)"\n\s*ADDRESS1="(.*)"\n\s*DEPARTMENT="(.*)"\n\s*CONTACT_PERSON="(.*)"\n\s*TELEPHONE="(.*)"\n\s*FAX="(.*)"\n\s*EMAIL="(.*)"'
>
> # shorter equivalent automated version
> pat = '="(.*)"\n\s*'.join(field_labels) + '="(.*)"'
> ```

---

### Code

```py
import re
import json

# Read from file or use the dummy data
with open("partner.txt", "r") as f:
    s = f.read()

field_labels = [
                'PARTNER', 
                'ADDRESS1', 
                'DEPARTMENT', 
                'CONTACT_PERSON', 
                'TELEPHONE', 
                'FAX', 
                'EMAIL'
                ]
# Define regex pattern and compile for speed
pat = '="(.*)"\n\s*'.join(field_labels) + '="(.*)"'
pat = re.compile(pat)

# Extract target fields
data = pat.findall(s)

# Prepare a list of dicts: each dict for a single block of data
d = [dict((k,v) for k,v in zip(field_labels, field_values)) for field_values in data]
text = json.dumps({'data': d}, indent=2)
print(text)
# Write to a json file
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

**Output**:

```py
# output.json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "PARTNER": "ABC",
      "ADDRESS1": "ABC Country INN",
      "DEPARTMENT": "ABC Department",
      "CONTACT_PERSON": "HR",
      "TELEPHONE": "+91.90.XX XX X XXX",
      "FAX": "+01.XX.XX XX XX XX",
      "EMAIL": ""
    },
    {
      "PARTNER": "DEF",
      "ADDRESS1": "DEF Malaysia",
      "DEPARTMENT": "",
      "CONTACT_PERSON": "",
      "TELEPHONE": "(YYY)YYYYY",
      "FAX": "(001)YYYYYYYY",
      "EMAIL": ""
    },
    {
      "PARTNER": "GEH-LOP",
      "ADDRESS1": "GEH LOP Street",
      "DEPARTMENT": "HR",
      "CONTACT_PERSON": "Adam",
      "TELEPHONE": "+91.ZZ.ZZ.ZZZZ",
      "FAX": "+91.ZZ.ZZ.ZZZ",
      "EMAIL": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

---

### Dummy Data

```py
# Dummy Data
s = """
PARTNER="ABC"
  ADDRESS1="ABC Country INN"
  DEPARTMENT="ABC Department"
  CONTACT_PERSON="HR"
  TELEPHONE="+91.90.XX XX X XXX"
  FAX="+01.XX.XX XX XX XX"
  EMAIL=""

PARTNER="DEF"
  ADDRESS1="DEF Malaysia"
  DEPARTMENT=""
  CONTACT_PERSON=""
  TELEPHONE="(YYY)YYYYY"
  FAX="(001)YYYYYYYY"
  EMAIL=""

PARTNER="GEH-LOP"
  ADDRESS1="GEH LOP Street"
  DEPARTMENT="HR"
  CONTACT_PERSON="Adam"
  TELEPHONE="+91.ZZ.ZZ.ZZZZ"
  FAX="+91.ZZ.ZZ.ZZZ"
  EMAIL=""
"""
```

Comment: @codenamebazinga Please take a look at this. I will suggest you to first try with the dummy data you shared and I pasted in my solution for reproducibility. This will form a baseline. Once that works, try it on data read from the file `partner.txt`.

Comment: It worked beautifully. Thanks a lot for a concrete solution.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please consider **`voting-up`** and **`accepting`** the answer. Thank you.